# GET call from corda.jar not recieved by api

Tags: get, corda, cordite

I am setting up a network map service, where the GET(request method of HTTP network map protocol) with path "/network-map/node-info/{hash}" will retrieve a signed NodeInfo as specified in the network map object. Issue is that, this method is not being invoked by the corda.jar.

I have followed the instructions in https://docs.corda.net/network-map.html#network-parameters-update-process. I have also referred to the cordite implementation of NMS. I am able to get a response from the GET method using postman.

the GET /network-map/node-info/{hash} method is necessary for updating the networkMapCache, which in turn enables a node to know its peers. Right now I have a network with 2 nodes that are not able to interact with each other due to this problem. If I run the ssh command "run networkMapSnapshot" I get only the nodeInfo of the node that is executing the command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to run your own network, take a look the network bootstrapping guide @ https://docs.corda.net/network-bootstrapper.html

It is difficult to identify your issues because there are a lot of steps to set-up a private network.

Comment: Thank You Li :) 
Network bootstrapper was avoided because I am trying to develop a Network Map Service for a production environment.